# Editing bootstrap - js versus min.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, workflow

Quick question, I'm editing a bootstrap template js, and there's 2 of them, the regular js and the minified. How do I approach editing it...should I edit both? Can I delete the minified one and then minify the regular js once I'm done with all the edits, or is there another more efficient way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a custom js file and overwrite whatever you want to change that's in bootstrap. Just make sure you render the the custom file after the bootstrap file. Don't edit both. Keep the min in the project and the regular as reference.

Comment: Thanks - could you please tell me why is bootstrap delivered with files like this, both expanded, regular js and css with whitespace and all, and minimized files? I'm starting (obviously) with this and it's confusing to see duplicates. It's downright given that every css and probably js file needs to be edited. So why ship regular one, minimized one and then you have to put your own custom on top. Is that a regular way when developing bootstrap site?

Comment: Mostly yes and thats typically all js and css frameworks. not just bootstrap, but essentially the min just loads and compiles faster.

Answer (score 0):

Most people (I think) create their own `custom.js` file, and load it **after** the bootstrap minified version. The non-minified version is there primarily so you can read it, IMO. There is no reason to load the non-min version if you're overriding with a custom file. This applies to both the css and js files. Your structure would look like this

```
<link href="http://yoursite.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://yoursite.com/assets/css/custom.css">

<script src="http://yoursite.com/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<script src="http://yoursite.com/assets/js/custom.js">
```

That being said, I know some people choose to edit the `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` files directly, and then load just one `css` and `js` file. While I understand the desire for fewer http calls, it's a bigger file so the speed-gain is reduced, but more importantly (again, for me) it's also harder to maintain and troubleshoot.